# Android target не установлен

Tags: cordova, sdk

Пробую настроить кордову+айоник для андроид разработки, поставил JDK, android sdk, прописал все системные переменные . Но почему-то cordova requirements выдает ошибку

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<initSchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<initSchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinitAndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
```

Comment: Уже нашли решение проблемы, или вопрос актуален?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем manifest.xml должна быть такая строчка:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Видимо, у вас не установлены `tools` для версии, которая соответствует таргету.

В Android Studio установить нужные версии тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если судить по [этому гайду](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/guide/platforms/android/), вам нужно просто установить нужные пакеты SDK:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />` есть строчка и свойствах проекта(project.properties) указана та же версия. В папке platfroms есть все версии платформ(от Android-15 до Android 26)

Comment: @ItsMyLife введите в консоль `android list target`, там будут нужные пакеты? Не уверен, что на windows также надо вызывать команду, попробуйте поискать